# How to check connectable flag from BLE Advertisement packet in android?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is the data which I received in by advertisement packet, I am unable to identify if the BLE message is connectable for not.

For ios I get 'kCBAdvDataIsConnectable': true this flag directly, but for Android I am unable to identify this flag

```
0 = 30
1 = -1
2 = 6
3 = 0
4 = 1
5 = 9
6 = 32
7 = 2
8 = 98
9 = -114
10 = 4
11 = 24
12 = -126
13 = 78
14 = -34
15 = -80
16 = -27
17 = 54
18 = -98
19 = -95
20 = -3
21 = 3
22 = 26
23 = 96
24 = 15
25 = 65
26 = 13
27 = 98
28 = 108
29 = 75
30 = 120
31 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method you are looking for: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult.html#isConnectable()

Comment: OnLeScan is a callback which gives data in form of byte array, I am not getting ScanResult object

Comment: Then you are using the old Android 4 API. Use the new Android 5 API https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBluetoothLeScanner()